# Android app name on device

Tags: android

I thought that

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

in `<application>` was needed to have the appname displayed on the device below the icon.
But all I get is blanks below the icon.
What am I missing?

Comment: I think `android:label="@string/app_name"` should be at `<activity>` tag.

Comment: show your menifest and string file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this feature in each Activity tag in your manifest.

Example:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.packagename.myActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: I had one Activity with label="". Changing it fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

In **strings.xml** app_name value may be empty or

you have to declare

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

in **activity** tag also